# if statement in nested foreach in tikzpicture not working - wrong syntax?

Tags: texstudio, foreach, ifthenelse, variable

I attempt to place dots on certain grid locations by using a nested \foreach command as follows, but TeXstudio rejects the use of the second variable \y with an error 'unrecognized command'.

Strangely enough the \y ***value*** in the \filldraw command ***is*** recognized: dots are placed on **all** grid points.
But apparently the if syntax that I used is not correct; the result is not depending on the 'unrecognized command' flag in TeXstudio. How to solve this?

```
\documentclass [a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5.0,cap=round,>=latex]
\draw[step=0.1cm,lightgray,very thin]  (0.0,0.0) grid (3.0,2.0);
\draw[thin] (0.0cm,0.0cm) -- (3.1cm,0.0cm) node[right,fill=white] {$x$};
\draw[thin] (0.0cm,0.0cm) -- (0.0cm,2.1cm) node[above,fill=white] {$y$};
\foreach \x in {0.1,0.2,...,2.8}{
    \foreach \y in {0.1,0.2,...,1.8}
    {
        if \x < \y {\filldraw[black] (\x cm, \y cm) circle(0.2pt);}
    }
}
\end{tikzpicture}       
\end{document}
```

[image]

EDIT

I noticed that the issue reported is not an issue at all; the code does do its job, but the result is not what I wished to achieve so I repost my question here with another title and tags.

From another post it looks that one needs to use a more complex approach: the following works fine:

```
        \pgfmathsetmacro\q {\y}
        \ifdim \q pt< \x pt
            \filldraw[black] (\x cm, \y cm) circle(0.2pt);
        \else {}
        \fi
```

It is unclear to me why it needs to be so complex. Is there a simpler solution?

Comment: The `\begin{document}` has been dropped!!

Comment: texstudio is just the editor you are using to write the file it is not related to any tex errors reprorted/

Comment: Given WME has no error in my TeXLive 2019. Do you have any TeX distribution? like [TeXlive](https://www.tug.org/texlive/) or [MikTeX](https://miktex.org/)?

Comment: I forgot to say, Welcome to TeX.SX

Comment: I maybe should have asked about correct if statement format. I read in other posts that the error does not prevent proper compile (hence the dots everywhere) but the if condition or format is then probably wrong?

Comment: @C.F.G I've edit the missing `\begin{document}` problem.